# Using Papeeria -- the second section isn't compiling at all

Tags: sectioning, compiling

Resolved!

In my document, I have two sections. The end document is after the second section (I checked). However, the second section isn't showing up at all on my compiled PDF.

Edit: it looks like the issue might be with pagination? Every time I try to pull section 2 onto a new page, it won't compile that page.

The current overall structure is as follows:

```
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Problem 1}

bla bla bla

\section{Problem 2}


 When working with reactions, it is often necessary to work with Gibbs energies, equilibrium constants, and concentrations. The solubility reaction plutonium oxide, shown below, 
 has a $\Delta G$ of 24.0 $\frac{kJ}{mol}$. First, we will explore this value with an uncertainty of $\pm 7$, and then we an uncertainty of $\pm 1$.

 $\mathbf{PuO_{2}(OH) (s) \rightarrow {PuO_{2}(OH) (aq)}}$

 $\Delta G = -RT ln(K_{eq})$

 $K_{eq} = \frac{[{PuO_{2}(OH) (s)]}{[{PuO_{2}(OH)(aq)]}$

 Given that the uncertainty in Gibbs energy is Gaussian, there is a range of numbers that should be plugged into the equation to find the range of $K_{eq}$ values. This can be done
 in a computer by finding random numbers and having it add and subtract those from $\Delta G$ to create a Gaussian distribution. The computer can then plug those values into the function to create a curve representing $K_eq$.

 Here is that curve given a Gibbs free energy of $24.0 \pm 7 frac{kJ}{mol}$.

 \begin{figure}[h!]
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{analyticalhomework1plusminus7.jpg}
 \end{figure}

 Here is that curve given a Gibbs free energy of $24.0 \pm 1 frac{kJ}{mol}$.

 \begin{figure}[h!]
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{analyticalhomework1plusminus1.jpg}
 \end{figure}

 Given that the solid is not in the solution, its concentration can be safely ignored, making the calculation of the concentration fairly straightforward. 

 Here is the concentration of the aqueous plutonium oxide given a Gibbs free energy of $24.0 \pm 7 frac{kJ}{mol}$.

 \begin{figure}[h!]
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{analyticalhomework1pm7conc.jpg}
 \end{figure}

 Here is the concentration given a Gibbs free energy of $24.0 \pm 1 frac{kJ}{mol}$.

 \begin{figure}[h!]
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{analyticalhomework1pm1conc.jpg}
 \end{figure}

 Clearly, even a fairly small uncertainty in the Gibbs free energy makes the $K_{eq}$ and the concentration of the product fairly difficult to identify.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you not have any packages or formatting that could affect how your sections are turning out?

Comment: I'm using:

amsmath, csquotes, placeins, cite, hanging, fontspec, graphicx

Comment: Ok. Have you checked that there isn't anything maybe at the end of your first section that "eats" the second one? Or some custom settings? It would be nice to have a complete file example from you to be able to properly attempt to solve this mystery. But if it is very large you could try commenting out settings/file sections systematically and compile to see if you can find the culprit (I have solved many errors that way).

Comment: Hm. I commented out the section titles, and that got rid of everything after the first page instead of after the second -- at a sort of random place in the document just after a table. Commenting out the table just filled in more text, but still stopped after the first page. Adding more text to the first section still stopped it after the second page like previously -- it seems like this is a pagination problem, not a section one?

Comment: That sounds very strange. It seems like there is something, a paragraph, page definition, environment or something that Latex is reading like a box that is too big to fit and won't break so the whole end of the document is sort of swallowed up into the "pagebreak". This has happened to me. Have you tried adding the third section? Or a section before the first one? To see if it still runs off at the second page or after the second section.

Comment: When it tries to pull my second section onto the second page, the second page vanishes, which makes sense with your theory. I've put the beginning of the vanishing section below.

\section{Problem 2}

When working with reactions, it is often necessary to work with Gibbs energies, equilibrium constants, and concentrations. The solubility reaction plutonium oxide, shown below, 
has a $\Delta G$ of 24.0 $\frac{kJ}{mol}$. First, we will explore this value with an uncertainty of $\pm 7$, and then we an uncertainty of $\pm 1$.

$\textbf{PuO_{2}(OH) (s) \rightarrow {PuO_{2}(OH) (aq)}$

Comment: Please fix your question, edit it so that the example shows the problem that you are asking about. The posted code has no problems. Look for a stray `\end{document}` in one of the sections.

Comment: I don't know if this is what was messing with your document, but for a start you need to use \mathbf in a math environment, and also there was no second curly bracket to close the bold environment. I put it on the end: $\mathbf{PuO_{2}(OH) (s) \rightarrow {PuO_{2}(OH) (aq)}}$. I tried putting it inbetween some text and it compiled fine

Comment: you will get a tex error from `$\textbf{PuO_`  if you get (any) error then do not look at the pdf except possibly for debugging it is not intended to be usable. If you want help with fixing an error show a small complete document that shows the error and show the  exact error from the log file, in a code block so line endings preserved.

Comment: I edited the main body of the post to add the entirety of section 2. I'm not getting any errors, actually, even before I fixed the bold face issue (Thanks!).

Comment: It works now???? I have no idea why???? I copied section 2 to a new document, commented it all out, and added it back in. I fixed a few errors here and there in my equations, but didn't run into the "you don't get to see the page" thing again? And then when I put it back it worked?????

Comment: That has happened to me, seemingly not "fixing" anything but all of a sudden it works. Good that you got it going. Next time you run into a problem I would recommend you to follow @DavidCarlisle's advice and include a full compilable example document in your question so that people who want to help you can do so easily without having to make up their own documents to guess what your problem might be. Happy latexing!